# Angular + meteor counter increment when button is pressed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, counter, increment

Im using meteor, angular and ionic for my project. I want to increase a counter when a certain button in a modal is pressed.  Then i want to display the value of this counter. 
My code is the following but it doesn't seem to work at all:

### Html

```
<button class="button button-clear button-positive" ng-click="timee(1)">
              Delay
</button>
```

### Controller

```
angular
  .module('Buschat')
  .controller('NewGoodCtrl', NewGoodCtrl);

function NewGoodCtrl($scope, $state, $meteor) {

  $scope.timecnt=0;

  $scope.hideModal = hideModal;
  $scope.timee = timee;

  function hideModal() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  }

  function timee(inc){
    $scope.timecnt += inc;
    $scope.modal.hide();
  }
```

Just to mention that when the line `$scope.timecnt += inc;` is deleted the hide modal function works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put your function inside a $scope variable then call it from the html file